# EF Core and Many to Many HttpPUT not working

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, put

I'm trying to use HtppPUT on many to many relationships between contacts and skills. My objects are like this:

Contacts:

```
 public class ContactDB
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public List<ContactSkill> ContactSkills { get; set; }
}
```

Skills :

```
public class SkillDB
{
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }

    public List<ContactSkill> ContactSkills { get; set; }
}
```

ContactSkills :

```
 public class ContactSkill
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactDB Contact { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public virtual SkillDB Skill { get; set; }
}
```

The context :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactDB>()
        .HasKey(c => c.ContactId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SkillDB>()
            .HasKey(s => s.SkillId);

        // Define link between Contacts and Skills
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactSkill>()
            .HasKey(cs => new { cs.ContactId, cs.SkillId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactSkill>()
            .HasOne(cs => cs.Contact)
            .WithMany(c => c.ContactSkills)
            .HasForeignKey(cs => cs.ContactId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactSkill>()
            .HasOne(cs => cs.Skill)
            .WithMany(s => s.ContactSkills)
            .HasForeignKey(cs => cs.SkillId);
    }
```

The Get, Delete, Post requests works.

But when I try to update a contact, I get to update it but not the associated Skills.
In the Controller, if I take a look of the Contact, it doesn't have Skills associate

[Context Contact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXer3.png)

Maybe that's why the update doesn't work, but I don't know why.